# why does the value of num2 in below expression becomes -1 instead of 0?

Tags: c, logical-operators

The below C program gives output `-1` for `num2`. I do not understand why. Can somebody help me with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = -1, num3 = -2, num4 = 1, ans;
    ans = num1++ && num2++ || ++num4 && num3++;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", num1, num2, num3, num4, ans);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 -1 -1 2 1
```

Comment: Homework? If not then don't write like this. Hopefully this is an exercise in how not to write code. If C is your first language, then learn another first (choose a language for learning). If you are experienced than consider Rust.

Comment: Yes, It is part of assignment to predict output. I will consider looking into Rust though.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `num1++ && num2++ || ++num4 && num3++` is parsed as:

```
(num1++ && num2++) || (++num4 && num3++)
```

Both `||` and `&&` use shortcut evaluation, meaning that the right operand if and only if the left operand evaluates to false (resp. true).

- `num1++ && num2++` is evaluated first:
- `num1++` is evaluated: it evaluates to the initial value of `num1`, `0` and `num1` is incremented.
- since the left operand if false, the right operand of `&&` is not evaluated (`num2` is unchanged`) and the expression is false:
- `num1++ && num2++` is false, so the right operand of `||` must be evaluated to determine the value of the whole expression:
- `++num4` is evaluated: the value is `2` and `num4` is incremented.
- the left operand of this second `&&` operator is true, so the right operand is evaluated
- `num3++` is evaluated: the value is `-2` and `num3` is incremented.
- `2 && -2` is true, the whole expression evaluates to true, which has type `int` and the value `1` in C: `ans` receives the value `1`.
- `printf` outputs `1 -1 -1 2 1` (without a trailing newline)

Answer (score 0):

If the left side of a logical AND `&&` is false, the right side will not be evaluated as the result can be determined as false already.